# Why does cx_Freeze rise this error when running an exe file?

Tags: python, cx-freeze, distutils

I am a new user of cx_Freeze and I wanted to package my python file with all needed dependencies.

I use **Python3**.

I work under a python virtualenv with dependencies such as `tensorflow, sklearn, matplotlib, python-vlc...`

Here are all files needed to reproduce the same error on Windows.

My **requirements.txt** to install

```
absl-py==0.7.0
altgraph==0.16.1
astor==0.7.1
audioread==2.1.6
certifi==2018.11.29
chardet==3.0.4
cx-Freeze==5.1.1
cycler==0.10.0
decorator==4.3.2
distlib==0.2.8
future==0.17.1
gast==0.2.2
grpcio==1.18.0
h5py==2.9.0
idna==2.8
Jinja2==2.10
joblib==0.13.1
Keras-Applications==1.0.7
Keras-Preprocessing==1.0.9
kiwisolver==1.0.1
librosa==0.6.2
llvmlite==0.27.0
macholib==1.11
Markdown==3.0.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
matplotlib==3.0.2
numba==0.42.0
numpy==1.16.1
pefile==2018.8.8
protobuf==3.6.1
py2exe==0.9.2.2
PyInstaller==3.4
pynsist==2.3
pyparsing==2.3.1
pypiwin32==223
pysrt==1.1.1
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-vlc==3.0.4106
pywin32==224
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
requests==2.21.0
requests-download==0.1.2
resampy==0.2.1
scikit-learn==0.20.2
scipy==1.2.0
six==1.12.0
sklearn==0.0
tensorboard==1.12.2
tensorflow==1.12.0
termcolor==1.1.0
tornado==5.1.1
urllib3==1.24.1
watson-developer-cloud==2.8.0
websocket-client==0.48.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
yarg==0.1.9
```

I have one main python file **`IHM.py`** that imports modules from two others python files **`sync.py`** and **`neurnet.py`**.

File **ihm.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# for Python3
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp
import tkinter.filedialog
from watson_developer_cloud import LanguageTranslatorV3
import json
import subprocess
import os
import vlc
from sync import *
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# Définition des variables globales
vid_file_path = ""
vid_srt_path = ""
vid_srt_path_trans = ""
vid_srt_path_sync = ""


# Création de la fenetre d'IHM
fenetre = Tk()
fenetre.title("Test Tkinter Windows")



fenetre.mainloop()
```

File **sync.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import division
from neuralNet import
```

File **neurnet.py**

```
#coding: utf-8
import os
import time
import sys
import librosa
import re
import io
import subprocess
import pysrt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import time
import tensorflow as tf
import pickle
#from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
#from tensorflow.contrib.layers import flatten
import sklearn



from subprocess import STDOUT

try:
    from subprocess import DEVNULL # py3k
except ImportError:
    import os
    DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'wb')
```

And here, the cx_Freeze **setup.py** :

```
# setup.py 
import sys, os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = 'C:/Program Files/Python36/tcl/tcl8.6' 
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = 'C:/Program Files/Python36/tcl/tk8.6'
__version__ = "1.1.0"

buildOptions = dict(
    packages = [],
    excludes = [],  includes = ["idna.idnadata"],
    include_files = ['C:/Program Files/Python36/DLLs/tcl86t.dll','C:/Program Files/Python36/DLLs/tk86t.dll'] )

import sys

base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None 
executables = [
    Executable('ihm.py', base=base) 
] 
setup(
    name = "mgp320",
    description='Projet Neural Network Speech Detection',
    version=__version__,
    options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
    executables = executables
)
```

Running this setup by using command : `python setup.py build`
So it creates me an exe file but when I run this exe I got this error window :

[Error cx_Freeze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpJ9r.png)

And the trackback is the following :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File
"C:\Users\achraf.bentabib\Desktop\aapsa\aapsa\env\lib\site-p
ackages\cx_Freeze\initscript\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
  module.run()
 File
"C:\Users\achraf.bentabib\Desktop\aapsa\aapsa\env\lib\site-p
ackages\cx_Freeze\initscript\Console.py", line 26, in run
  exec(code, m.__dict__)
 File "ihm.py", line 5, in <module>
 File
"C:\Users\achraf.bentabib\Desktop\aapsa\aapsa\env\lib\site-p
ackages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 120, in <module>
   import distutils.version
 File
"C:\Users\achraf.bentabib\Desktop\aapsa\aapsa\env\lib\distut
ils\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
   loader.exec_module(real_distutils)
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674, in
exec_module
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 780, in
get_code
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 832, in
get_data
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
"C:\\Users\\achraf.bentabib\\Desktop\\aapsa\\aapsa\\stack\\b
uild\\exe.win-amd64-3.6\\lib\\library.zip\\distutils\\__init__.py'
```

I really don't know how can I fix that..

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. And please post the error message and full stack trace as text, not as an image, see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/8516269)

Comment: So i've done it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution for the last traceback:

```
from distutils import dist, sysconfig # isort:skip 
ImportError: cannot import name "dist"
```

The problem is that `distutils` doesn't have many module that are not installed in the virtualenv. (only `__init__.py`)
So when we build the exe, it doesn't find the distutils modules...

To fix that we have to manually import disutils

```
import distutils
import opcode
import os
distutils_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(opcode.__file__), 'distutils')
```

And then, include this path to the include_files options of cx_freeze, and
exclude distutils in the excludes section.

```
buildOptions = dict(
    packages = ['llvmlite', 'pkg_resources._vendor', "tkinter", 'numba', "tkinter.filedialog", "audioread", "librosa", "scipy", "numpy"],
    excludes = ["scipy.spatial.cKDTree", 'distutils'],
    includes = ["idna.idnadata", 'numpy.core._methods', 'numpy.lib.format', 'matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg'],
    include_files = [(distutils_path, 'distutils'), 'C:/Program Files/Python36/DLLs/tcl86t.dll','C:/Program Files/Python36/DLLs/tk86t.dll']
)
```

I have also add `pkg_resources._vendor` in the packages because without this, cx_freeze raise an error like

```
ImportError: The 'appdirs' package is required; normally this is bundled with th
is package so if you get this warning, consult the packager of your distribution
```

Finally it work, I added `numba`to the package to includes because like for disutils, build doesn't create all required modules (for librosa).

The last problem was about `multiprocessing` lib.
I have to manually rename `Pool.pyc` to `pool.py`c in the build lib folder.

Comment: Did you manage to freeze with tensorflow without error?

Comment: @user13640482 yes

Answer (score 3):

I see the following potential problems in your setup script for `cx_Freeze` 5.1.1:

1. You are using `numpy` (and `matplotlib` which depends on `numpy`). In order that `cx_Freeze` correctly freezes `numpy`, it needs to be added to the `packages` list of the `build_exe` options.
2. For `cx_Freeze` version 5.1.1, the TCL/TK DLLs need to be included in a `lib` subdirectory of the build directory. You can do that by passing a tuple `(source, destination)` to the corresponding entry of the `include_files` list option. Furthermore, it would be safer to dynamically find out the location of the TCL/TK DLLs.

Altogether, try with the following modifications in your setup script:

```py
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

buildOptions = dict(
    packages = ["numpy"],
    excludes = [],
    includes = ["idna.idnadata"],
    include_files=[(os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
                    os.path.join('lib', 'tk86t.dll')),
                   (os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'),
                    os.path.join('lib', 'tcl86t.dll'))]
)
```

If it still does not work with this modification, start from a minimal `tkinter` application, for example by commenting out all imports but `tkinter` in the example application you have posted and make it work on your system. Re-add then the modules you need one by one (`numpy`, `matplotlib`, ...) and check that the unfrozen and frozen applications work at each step. You can for example add a message box to the example application and print there the version of each module you import.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It stilldoes not work. But i've fix bug from all imports except those of 'librosa'. Cx_freeze raise an error about the 'distutils' package. I tried to add i manually to library.zip with 'zip_include_packages' arguments of buildOptions...But stil doesn't work

Comment: @AchrafBentabib At least it seems we are getting closer. Try to add "librosa" and "audioread" to the `packages`list. And according to the documentation, `librosa` requires `scipy`, which itself needs additional tuning for cx_Freeze: add "scipy" to the `packages` list and "scipy.spatial.cKDTree" to the `excludes` list.

Comment: @AchrafBentabib If this still does not work please post the full stack trace of the new error.

Comment: Thanks @jpeg, I modify as you said, but still not working..See bellow for the new stack trace